# display data from table with ajax laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to show the data of table in a form for updating it.

So I'm using this code :

```
@foreach($castings as $cast)
    <div class="card d-flex flex-row mb-3">
        <a class="d-flex" href="Pages.Product.Detail.html">
            <img src="img/products/fat-rascal-thumb.jpg" alt="Fat Rascal"
                 class="list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left"/>
        </a>
        <div class="pl-2 d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
            <div
                class="card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-lg-center">
                <a href="Pages.Product.Detail.html" class="w-40 w-sm-100">
                    <p class="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate">{{ $cast->casting_name }}</p>
                </a>
                <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100">{{ $cast->casting_cin }}</p>
                <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100">{{ $cast->casting_email }}</p>
                <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100">{{ $cast->casting_phone }}</p>
                <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100">{{ $cast->casting_gender }}</p>
                <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100">{{ $cast->casting_address }}</p>
                <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100">{{ $cast->casting_city }}</p>
                <div class="w-15 w-sm-100">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">PROCESSED</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-1 align-self-center pr-4">
                <a href="#" class="glyph-icon iconsminds-folder-edit editbtn"></a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
<div class="modal fade" id="castingmodeledit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <form method="post" class="needs-validation tooltip-label-right" id="formcastedit" novalidate
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id"/>

            <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="casting_name" id="casting_name">
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">Name is required!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                <label>CIN</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="casting_cin" id="casting_cin" required>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">CIN is required!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                <label>EMAIL</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_email" id="casting_email" required>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">EMAIL is required!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                <label>PHONE</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_phone" id="casting_phone" required>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">PHONE is required!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group position-relative">
                <label>Radio</label>
                <div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" id="jQueryCustomRadio1" name="casting_gender" id="casting_gender"
                               class="custom-control-input" required value="homme">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="jQueryCustomRadio1">Homme</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" id="jQueryCustomRadio2" name="casting_gender" id="casting_gender"
                               class="custom-control-input" required value="femme">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="jQueryCustomRadio2">Femme</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                <label>ADDRESS</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_address" id="casting_address" required>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">ADDRESS is required!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                <label>CITY</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_city" id="casting_city" required>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">CITY is required!</div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" id="createBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
    integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.editbtn').on('click', function (e) {
            $('#castingmodeledit').modal('show');

            $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            
            var data = $tr.children("td").map(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();

            console.log(data);
            
            $('#casting_name').val(data[1]);
            $('#casting_cin').val(data[2]);
            $('#casting_email').val(data[3]);
            $('#casting_phone').val(data[4]);
            $('#casting_gender').val(data[5]);
            $('#casting_address').val(data[6]);
            $('#casting_city').val(data[7]);
        });
    });

</script>
```

But it does not display anything in the modal form

since I don't have the `<td>` and `<tr>` in my form I didn't know how to use them later in the ajax script

I tried to add the `tr` and `td` balise in my form but the same problem

please if you have any idea help me

**Edit**

I tried that

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){



        $('.editbtn').on('click', function(e) {

             $('#castingmodeledit').modal('show');
    
                     var selector = $(this).closest('.card-body'); //get closest card div
                  //use .find to get values and set inside inputss
                  $('#casting_name').val(selector.find(".casting_name").text());
                  $('#casting_cin').val(selector.find(".casting_cin").text());
                  $('#casting_phone').val(selector.find(".casting_phone").text());


 
});
</scipt>
```

But doesn't work

**Edit2**

```
<div class="card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-lg-center">
                            <a href="Pages.Product.Detail.html" class="w-40 w-sm-100">
                                <p class="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate">{{ $cast->casting_name }}</p>
                            </a>
                            <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100">{{ $cast->casting_cin }}</p>
                            <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100">{{ $cast->casting_phone }}</p>
                             
                        </div>
```

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="casting_name" id="casting_name"
value="{{ old('casting_name') }}"  >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give classes to your `p` tags inside your `card` .Then , whenever user click on `edit` simply use `.closest` and `.find()` to get values from `p` tags and show them inside modal inputs .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.editbtn').on('click', function(e) {
  var selector = $(this).closest('.card'); //get closest card div
  //use .find to get values and set inside inputss
  $('#casting_name').val(selector.find(".name").text());
  $('#casting_cin').val(selector.find(".cin").text());
  $('#casting_email').val(selector.find(".email").text());
  $('#casting_phone').val(selector.find(".phone").text());
  $('#castingmodeledit input[value=' + selector.find(".gender").text().trim() + ']').prop('checked', true);
  $('#casting_address').val(selector.find(".address").text());
  $('#casting_city').val(selector.find(".city").text());
  $('#castingmodeledit').modal('show');

});
```

```css
.invalid-tooltip {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="card d-flex flex-row mb-3">
  <a class="d-flex" href="Pages.Product.Detail.html">
    <img src="img/products/fat-rascal-thumb.jpg" alt="Fat Rascal" class="list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left" />
  </a>
  <div class="pl-2 d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
    <div class="card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-lg-center">
      <!--added classes-->
      <a href="Pages.Product.Detail.html" class="w-40 w-sm-100">
        <p class="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate name">abcw22</p>
      </a>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 cin">2</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 email">a@gmaile.com</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 phone">13456</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 gender">homme</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 address">abwwc xyz..</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 city">Mum</p>
      <div class="w-15 w-sm-100">
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">PROCESSED</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-1 align-self-center pr-4">
                                  <a href="#" class="glyph-icon iconsminds-folder-edit editbtn" >Edit</a>
                            </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card d-flex flex-row mb-3">
  <a class="d-flex" href="Pages.Product.Detail.html">
    <img src="img/products/fat-rascal-thumb.jpg" alt="Fat Rascal" class="list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left" />
  </a>
  <div class="pl-2 d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
    <div class="card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-lg-center">
      <a href="Pages.Product.Detail.html" class="w-40 w-sm-100">
        <p class="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate name">abcw</p>
      </a>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 cin">1</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 email">a@gmail.com</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 phone">134536</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 gender">homme</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 address">abwwc xyz..</p>
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100 city">Mum</p>
      <div class="w-15 w-sm-100">
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">PROCESSED</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-1 align-self-center pr-4">
                                  <a href="#" class="glyph-icon iconsminds-folder-edit editbtn" >Edit</a>
                            </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="castingmodeledit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <form method="post" class="needs-validation tooltip-label-right" id="formcastedit" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id" />

      <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="casting_name" id="casting_name">
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">Name is required!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
        <label>CIN</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="casting_cin" id="casting_cin" required>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">CIN is required!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
        <label>EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_email" id="casting_email" required>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">EMAIL is required!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
        <label>PHONE</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_phone" id="casting_phone" required>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">PHONE is required!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group position-relative">
        <label>Radio</label>
        <div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="jQueryCustomRadio1" name="casting_gender" id="casting_gender" class="custom-control-input" required value="homme">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="jQueryCustomRadio1">Homme</label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="jQueryCustomRadio2" name="casting_gender" id="casting_gender" class="custom-control-input" required value="femme">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="jQueryCustomRadio2">Femme</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
        <label>ADDRESS</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_address" id="casting_address" required>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">ADDRESS is required!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
        <label>CITY</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_city" id="casting_city" required>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">CITY is required!</div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" id="createBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

      <div class="result"></div>

    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ; where can I put this code     .invalid-tooltip {
  display: none
}

Comment: That part you can add inside `css` . but , i have added because i am not sure if you want to show `invalid-tooltip` inside modal or not .

Comment: did you add class to `p` tags or not ? Like i have added in html ?

Comment: `casting_name` should be added here `<p class="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate casting_name">{{ $cast->casting_name }}</p>` same for other `p` tag as well .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232916/discussion-between-swati-and-user14053977).